# How to upload image and file with Froala editor in MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, froala

How to upload image and file with Froala editor in MEAN stack.

I am using Froala Editor V3. I got data but image and files can't get. I am shaw that official website. but also am not clear.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have done this but in net core. Still could point you in the right direction if needed.

Comment: Yeah, i have done this in MEAN stack.